# PySide QLineEdit not appearing

Tags: python, user-interface, alignment, pyside, qlineedit

I am learning PySide and I can't seem to get `QLineEdit` to appear. My best guess is because the `QTextEdit` is set as as the main widget and is covering it up. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle("A Text Editor")
    self.setGeometry(300,1000,500,500)
    self.fileName = QtGui.QLineEdit('File Name')    
    self.fileName.resize(self.fileName.sizeHint())

    self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.text)

    menubar = self.menuBar()
    exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'),'&Exit',self)
    exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
    saveAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('save.png'),'&Save',self)
    saveAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
    saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)

    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
    fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
    self.show()

  def save(self):
    f = open(self.fileName.text(),'w')
    f.write(self.text.toPlainText())
    f.close()

def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  win = Window()
  exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to set a central widget with some form of layout to get them to both appear.

Something like:

```
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(self.fileName)
layout.addWidget(self.text)
centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Try These Codes :

```
#####################################################     1     #####################################################♀
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class main(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.scroll = QScrollArea()
    self.widget = QTextEdit()
    self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
    self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

    
    self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)
    self.setWindowTitle("Text Editor")
    self.resize(700,600)
    self.show()


app1 = QApplication([])
window = main()
app1.exec()





#####################################################     2     #####################################################♀
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class main(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.widget = QWidget()
    self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
    self.label = QLabel("Text Editor")
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
    self.vbox.addWidget(QTextEdit())

    self.label.setFont(QFont("Tahoma", 30))  
    self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)  
    
    self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
    self.setWindowTitle("Text Editor")
    self.resize(700,600)
    self.show()


app2 = QApplication([])
window = main()
app2.exec()





#####################################################     3     #####################################################♀
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class main(QTextEdit):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()


    self.setWindowTitle("Text Editor")
    self.resize(700,600)
    self.show()


app3 = QApplication([])
window = main()
app3.exec()
```